# The problem of scrolling of horizontal collectionview in tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i have a tableview with custom cells every cell has a horizontal collectionView. So, when reload tableView i get the data in tableview correctly so the first tableViewCell is working well with the collection view but the other cells have the scroll not from beginning

i tried to make a collectionview in tableView cell it works fine but the scroll does not work as i need

```
    extension HomeVC:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (self.viewModel.homee?.data?.banners?.count ?? 0) + 1
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return HelpingMethods.setProductHeight() + 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueCellForTable(ofType: ProductSliderCell.self)

                cell.configureCell(banner.content, nil,0)
                return cell

    }
}
```

**and for the collection view i use this code**

```
class ProductSliderCell: UITableViewCell {



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    collectionView.registerNibForCollection(ofType: productItem.self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

```
    extension ProductSliderCell:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return  self.contentOffers?.products?.count ?? 0


    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueCellForCollection(ofType: productItem.self, withIndex: indexPath)
        if let product = self.content?.products?[indexPath.item] {
                cell.configureCellForHome(product)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/2.8, height:  HelpingMethods.setProductHeight())
    }
}
```

i did not get as i expect i think it is because the reuse of cell

Comment: What is your expected behavior and how is it behaving right now? Maybe you need to explicitly specify for your collectionViews that they are going to be scrolled horizontally only?

Comment: in first cell the scroll begin from the first item and in other cells it does not begin with first item

Comment: What do you mean by saying `the scroll begin`? Can you add a screenshot with a correct cell and a wrong one? Do you mean the margin? Or what?

Comment: let me explain more if i have 10 tableview Cells every tableView cell has a horizontal collectionview with 10 items when i run the project the first tableview cell begin the collectionview from the first item and other collectionview does not begin from the beginning clear now ?

Comment: So you are saying that the contentOffset of the first collectionView cell is 0, but the content offset for the next one is > 0 ? If that is the case, try adding collectionView.contentOffset = 0 to your numberOfItemsInsection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens usually in RTL direction apps, when the cell gets reused, it does not dismiss the position it had, in the cell before it

the solution is to always force UICollectionView to be flipped, every time the cell loads, using the collectionView's flow layout attribute `flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection` to return true,

1) Create a custom flow layout class with the following properties:

```
class ArabicCollectionFlow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    }
    override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

in your Tableviewcell class, in `awakeFromNib` to make sure that the nib is loaded, ignoring the fact it was reused, you're going to set the collectionView flow layout to be the one we created above

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    categories.collectionViewLayout = ArabicCollectionFlow()
}
```

Keep noted that this flow layout has to be set after your `reloadData`

Also, you may only need to use this solution if your app is running in RTL mode, so you can do your checks before using this custom layout